# Getting a NullPointerException when loading an image

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to print a report designed by iReport (5.0.4).
This report uses a company logo (logo.png).
When I remove this image from the report everything works fine.
When I leave it in the report, the report execution crashes.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:1034)

I am loading the picture in Java.

```
BufferedImage logo = null;
 try {
  logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
     } catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new ReportException(ex.getMessage());
  }
try {
 JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(reportName);
 parameter.put("SUBREPORT", report);
 parameter.put("SUBREPORTDS", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(subreport));
 ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                    "resources.Brief", Locale.GERMAN,
                    getClass().getClassLoader());
 parameter.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", resourceBundle);
 parameter.put("logo", logo);
 JasperReport baseReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(BASE_REPORT);
 JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(baseReport, parameter,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(nutzerListe));
 return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jprint);
```

The image is found, loaded and send to the report as a parameter "logo".

The report parameter itself is defined as:

```
< parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.Object" />
```

The image is defined in the report as:

```
 < image scaleImage="RealSize">
       < reportElement uuid="2e5316ac-fc10-4658-92b5-4cf7714b1c22" x="252" y="3" width="201" height="33"/>
       < imageExpression>< ![CDATA[$P{logo}]]>< /imageExpression>
    </image>
```

When I debug into the code (Jasperreport 3.7.4) the exception is thrown because in the method evaluateImage the expressionClass is null.
**Is there anyone with an idea?**

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to deal with images in JasperReports:
 
***1:*** By passing the string of the path. Unfortunately when you pass an image from your java code, it will work only with absolute paths (if you try with a relative path even if it's correct it won't work). So, in my example, i'm loading getting the absolute path of an image which is stored inside my application directory tree in this way:

```
 String front=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/Cards_Template/front.jpg");
 parameters.put("front", front);
```

At this point, you have just to pass this parameter to the image component on iReport:
[image]


***2:*** By passing them as InputStreams. Don't know exactly why, but it seems that only images with a static path (from the report itself) works with the image component. Anyway, the idea is that you should open/load the image as an `InputStream` object type, and change the expression type on iReport. I'm posting some images:
[image]
[image]

The code should be something like:

```
    InputStream front = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    parameters.put("front", front);
```

NOTE: In my example i'm generating the image from the code, you can load it just like you did on your example.